# How to make command+arrow go to begining and end of line in iterm2?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, iterm2

With the default settings, `command + arrow_left` switches to the tab on the left. How to change it so that it puts the cursor at the beginning of the line instead ?

Answer (score 42):

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell)

> - Go to settings (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
> - Go to tab `Keys`
> - Under "Key Bindings"
> - Change entry <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to Send Hex code: 0x01
> - Change entry <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to Send Hex code: 0x05

Visual:
[image: Visual of iTerm 2 Settings]

Comment: You can also set up Option+arrow keys to jump words by setting up `Option + left arrow` to `escape sequence` and key `b`, and `Option + right arrow` to `escape sequence` and key `f`.

Comment: @JamonHolmgren - I can't see `escape sequence` in the menu, the menu is huge! which sub-section is it in?

Comment: @ToniLeigh Just scan down until you start seeing "Send..." items. It's in there.

Comment: Here's a link to a screenshot: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1479215/11107105/5362a8b6-888f-11e5-913d-f5dac0a318ca.png

Comment: I think this should be included as a default keybinding.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm!

Comment: The correct binding is ⌘←  "SEND ESC SEQ" `OH` for Home and ⌘→  "SEND ESC SEQ" `OF` for End (those are uppercase 'o's not zeros). This simulates actually pressing the Home and End keys, and as such will work in bash, vim, etc.
I got this from a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10485061/391034 (didn't find a way to link a comment)

Answer (score 15):

I would say mapping keys manually, as shown in other answers, is an advanced setup. iterm2 already has preset for that.

- Open Preferences
- Click "Profile" tab
- Select a profile in the list on the left (eg "Default")
- Click "Keys" tab
- Click "Key Mappings" tab (if it exists)
- Click the "Presets" dropdown and select "Natural Text Editing"

After that, you can easily navigate in the console with the Command + Left/Right arrow.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. No need to mess around with the low-level settings.